# Change color of jquery pageguide on runtime

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a .NET core application with a [jquery pageguide](http://labs.sprint.ly/jquery.pageguide/) in it. The colors of the application, for example the menubars, can be configured by the user. 
To achieve this, I add a `HtmlString` with a `<style>` tag from a Controller. In the tag are the user specific colors in classes.

```
var primaryColor = "rgb(28,67,104)"; //will be configurable
return new HtmlString(($".primarycolor{{background-color:{primaryColor}; }}"));
```

I want to make the colors of the jquery pageguide configurable by the user, but the color values in the pageguide.css file can't obviously be modified. I read about LESS, but i cant (and shouldn't) compile it on runtime.

*How can I add dynamic color support to the pageguide? Is there an relative easy way to do this with js or server side code?*

Answer (score 0):

1. Read the users input by sending it to your .NET application
2. when rendering your page, overwrite it by generating a CSS-file or `<style>` tag which you can then implement on your HTML file. That CSS overwrites the default colors.